# Story about reincarnated warrior who gets his old tattoos and swords then goes on a quest

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, magical-items

I read it a couple years ago and it was about a warrior who died and then was resurrected. He got his old tattoos and swords which are magical artifacts then was asked to go on a quest to some kind of tower to stop some kind of mutant things. At some point he meets a race of dog men mutant things that he ends up becoming in charge of by killing their pack leader. He may have also awoken from his reincarnation with amnesia. It may be a middle book in a series. I think his quest may end in him destroying an orb that allows magic to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you are looking for [The Swords of Night and Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Swords_of_Night_and_Day) by David Gemmell, the 11th book in *The Drenai Saga*.

[image: Book cover]

> .... The book is set 1000 years following the death of Olek Skilgannon.
>
> The novel is an exploration of the future of the Drenai world, focussing heavily on Jiamads (joinings of beast and men honed to fighting perfection). The story also contains a satisfactory ending to Skilganon's original life, including not only his first demise, but that of Jianna, the Witch Queen with whom he was deeply in love. The story however appears to deal broadly with the idea of resurrection and life-after-death, albeit in a living, breathing world.

Skilgannon is known for his tattoos, and [the Google Book excerpt I found](https://books.google.com/books?id=qN5WpibBXlsC&pg=PT74&lpg=PT74&dq=skilgannon%20tattoos&source=bl&ots=iInoEv3Oqb&sig=PNNiaRYaf9f0vO9KdFmtPL1Y3LE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHho24kpzPAhUDOT4KHX2MDCkQ6AEIRjAL#v=onepage&q=skilgannon%20tattoos&f=false) seems to indicate that he does indeed get them back, as well as the two eponymous swords.

Comment: I have not read the books, but I'm thinking that the "Jiamads" might be the dog men mutant things". And indeed, both of him have amnesia after recincarnating (it's complicated).

Comment: That is it. Thanks the title of that book has been evading me for ages.